# How to halt datatask thread for some time while executing another datatask thread in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios7

I want to halt datatask one till my second datatask complete. How i can halt my first datatask .Here is my below code, in datatask one i have again started second datatask but i want to halt datatask one.

I am very new to ios swift programming so please me with this problem or you can give some alternate way to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
    let firsttask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
{
       // There is some logic but after this I started below second task


          let secondtask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
           //some logic
            }secondtask.resume()

  }firsttask.resume()
```

Comment: Please search for [datatask asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+datatask+asynchronous) or similar. You need a completion handler. The question has been asked may many time.

Answer (score 0):

When your first task completes it's routine(request), then completion closure gets called. That means your first task is no longer downloads anything and connection with the server is closed. So there is nothing you could halt with the first task at that point.

If you want to complete the second task first, just swap the order of tasks.

```
    let secondtask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
    {
       // There is some logic but after this I started below second task

            let firsttask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
           //some logic
            } firsttask.resume()

    }secondtask.resume()
```

Comment: I can't do that beacause there is some logic written in firsttask after that only second task need to start. So is there any alternate way to do this thing ???

Answer (score -1):

Yes using DispatchSemaphore you can achieve this. Check the below code usage.

```
var sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0) // Create a semaphore

let secondtask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
    {
       // There is some logic but after this I started below second task

            let firsttask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
           //some logic

           self.sem.signal() // Give signal to semaphore after completing 2nd task.

            } firsttask.resume()

    }secondtask.resume()

_ = sem.wait(timeout: .distantFuture) // wait or halt your thread.
```

any doubt plz comment.

Comment: I can't swap the task. Is there any other way to those things?

Comment: what do you mean I can't swap the task ?

Comment: See in the above code, your data task1 will get called, then on completing data task1, your 2nd task will start executing, then when your 2nd task is over then your control will be free.